# Use Context and an API Client handling a token from storage

Tags: reactjs, api, jwt, react-hooks, react-context

I'm currently working on a project in which I can fetch datas after a user has logged in.

I want the token to persist even after a reload of the page or when the user returns.

I also wanted to implement the `useReducer` for my fetch actions and use it inside one or multiple `contexts` to manage the data of my app.

Knowing that, I have some questions :

- Do I code my fetches in an ApiClient file, which then gets called upon the dispatch of certain actions ? Or do I put every call inside a function in my context ?
- How do I manage the storage of the token ? In my ApiClient or in my `initalState` of the context ?
- What about splitting my data in multiple contexts sharing the same base user context ? Or do I do one huge Context ?

Thanks in advance for the answers / discussions, do not hesitate if you need more informations.

Regards